# phpword me descarga el archivo como .docx.html en telefonos

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

estoy en un proyecto en el cual debo generar un informe por word, estoy usando phpword para lograrlo. todo funciona bien se descarga y lo puedo generar desde una plantilla de word, el asunto es cuando lo descargo desde un telefono, cuanndo le doy descargar desde el telefono el archivo se descarga con la extension .docx.html por lo que no es posible abrirlo de forma correcta en el telefono he buscado y sin exito una solucion asi que recurro al foro NOTA:(en chrome y los demas navegadores la esxtension si queda en .docx)

```
<?php

include("../../conexiones/conexion.php");

require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$templateProcessor = new PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("plantilla.docx");


$id = base64_decode($_GET['i']);

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM 'table_name' WHERE id = $idtable");

if ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


$valoracion = $res['date_val'];
$fech_valo = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $valoracion)));

$day= strtotime($dato1);
$dia = date('d',$day);
$month= strtotime($dato1);
$mes = date('m',$day);
$year= strtotime($dato1);
$ano = date('Y',$day);

$templateProcessor->setValue('d', $dia);
$templateProcessor->setValue('m', $mes);
$templateProcessor->setValue('yy', $ano);

$templateProcessor->setValue('msm', $res['dato2']);
$templateProcessor->setValue('valoracion', $res['dato3']);
$templateProcessor->setValue('analisis', $res['dato4']);

}
$templateProcessor->saveAs("savefile.docx");

$name = "CONCEPTO INICIAL ".$res['full_name'];

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name.doc.docx");

echo file_get_contents("savefile.docx");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes del header de `Content-Disposition` necesitas agregar otro header con el tipo de archivo que vas a transferir, para este caso necesitas un:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
```

Existen diferentes `Content-type` para cada tipo de archivo y su extensión.

Comment: Rafael Bautista Muchas gracias eso resolvio mi problema la verdad es que si olvide por completo esa parte de verdad gracias

Comment: una observacion es que ahora el vnd.ms-word ahora es msword